# Dashboard for HITs created using API on Mechanical Turk

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I have created a HIT using DotNet API and published it to production on Amazon Mechanical turk platform. I can see the HIT in the search results when I log into MTurk using a different Worker account. But, I am wondering if there is going to be any dashboard to monitor the progress of the HITs posted to production using the API. I know that there is a nice dashboard for the HITs created using the web interface provided by amazon MTurk requestor account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, no prebuilt dashboard, other then the one "Manage HITs individually" page. Anything you do with the API you really need to manage yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also, I would like to know if we can write javascript code inside the HTML design layout editor provided by MTurk while creating a project using the web interface. I have modified the HTMl code but I would like to do some validations as well. Is it possible?